# Should we allow crash logs to be posted

Tags: discussion

I notice that there is at least one question that has pasted a window of the Apple Crash reporter. However to find the cause it is often needed to see the whole crash log.

For Apple exchange should we be accepting questions that require this much information ie a paste of the crash log or this this too much detail and too specific?

Comment: Are there any legal implications with this? There may be some "confidential Apple information" in there. Just don't want them to get mad at us about it.

Comment: The only time there may be "confidential information" is if you're under an NDA otherwise it's all fine to post online.

Comment: Ok cool. I just didn't know if the crash logs were covered under the NDA as well.

Comment: Depending on the NDA and log: it's sometimes easy to see from a log that software is (or should be) subject to NDA. For link purposes: [Update to FAQ regarding beta and pre-release software](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/q/573/8546) and http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I say [yes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/how-to-read-a-crash-report-as-a-user). There are certain things you can learn from the crash report and the more information the better someone can answer the question. There will be instances where it will be too localised to answer but I think these will be in the minority.

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience analyzing crash logs, and I'm happy to look at one when provided with a question. I suggest anyone requesting a crash log set expectations and state that the log might not help solve the problem.

As an example, my comment for [this Eudora crash question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39660/eudora-crashes-under-snow-leopard-when-checking-mail) is:

> Could you include a full crash log in your question? Just be aware
>   that it is rare but not impossible that the crash log will indicate
>   the problem to someone reading your question.